# Is there a way to simplify the code using an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, button

Is there a way to simplify the below code by using an array? For example, when button 1 (with the index of 0) in the HTML is clicked, could that be used to get a value at index 0 in another array?

```js
function f1() {
  document.getElementById("dis").innerHTML = "JoeMae";
}

function f2() {
  document.getElementById("dis").innerHTML = "TanakaMae";
}

function f3() {
  document.getElementById("dis").innerHTML = "James";
}

function f4() {
  document.getElementById("dis").innerHTML = "Deus";
}
```

```html
<button onclick="f1()">no.1</button>
<button onclick="f2()">no.2</button>
<button onclick="f3()">no.3</button>
<button onclick="f4()">no.4</button>
<p id="dis"></p>
```

Comment: You can use a switch loop and apply `addEventListener` to the `document.getElementById();` and apply the same ID to all the buttons (not much reliable, as IDs are supposed to be "unique") or `document.getElementsByClass();` and apply the same class to the buttons (better approach)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an approach that's vanilla JS. I used the `dataset` API to connect each button to its data, then a single handler to retrieve and display this data.

```js
"use strict";
function byId(id){return document.getElementById(id)}
function newEl(tag){return document.createElement(tag)}

window.addEventListener('load', onLoaded, false);
function onLoaded(evt)
{
 var responseArray = ['JoeMae', 'TanakaMae', 'James', 'Deus'];
 responseArray.forEach( function(arrElem, elemIndex, arr)
       {
        var btn = newEl('button');
        btn.textContent = `no.${elemIndex+1}`;
        btn.dataset.response = arrElem;
        btn.addEventListener('click', onClick, false);
        document.body.appendChild(btn);
       }
      );
      
 function onClick(evt)
 {
  let text = this.dataset.response;
  byId('dis').textContent = text;
 }
}
```

```html
<p id='dis'></p>
```

Comment: do i need to install dependencies here or not?

Comment: Nope, there aren't any. Just a new browser running JS.

Answer (score 5):

You can simplify without using array:

```
<button onclick="f('JoeMae')">no.1</button>
<button onclick="f('TanakaMae')">no.2</button>
<button onclick="f('James')">no.3</button>
<button onclick="f('Deus')">no.4</button>
<p id="dis"></p>
```

```
function f(str) {
  document.getElementById("dis").innerHTML = str;
}
```

Comment: what does str mean?

Comment: it means "any string you can put as argument"

Comment: @maetanaka `str` is just name of this function argument, you can call it whatever you want

Comment: Inline handlers are almost never desirable, see https://www.w3.org/wiki/The_principles_of_unobtrusive_JavaScript . This also results in very repetitive code when there are lots of buttons

Answer (score 3):

Use another array such that the nth index of that array corresponds to the nth button:

```js
const texts = [
  "JoeMae",
  "TanakaMae",
  "James",
  "Deus"
];
const dis = document.getElementById("dis");
document.querySelectorAll('button').forEach((button, i) => {
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    dis.textContent = texts[i];
  });
});
```

```html
<button>no.1</button>
<button>no.2</button>
<button>no.3</button>
<button>no.4</button>
<p id="dis"></p>
```

Note that unless you're deliberately inserting HTML markup, you should probably use `textContent`, not `innerHTML`. (`textContent` is faster and safer)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a slightly cleaner and more flexible example how to implement this type of functionality.

If you are having a lot of rendering functionality like this, I would recommend you to use a library/framework for it, though.

```js
const buttonDefinitions = [
    {title: 'no.1', name: 'Monica'},
    {title: 'no.2', name: 'Erica'},
    {title: 'no.3', name: 'Rita'},
    {title: 'no.4', name: 'Tina'}
];


const buttonContainer = document.getElementById('buttonContainer');
const resultContainer = document.getElementById('resultContainer');

for (const buttonDefinition of buttonDefinitions) {
    const button = document.createElement('button');
    button.innerHTML = buttonDefinition.title;
    button.onclick = () => {
        resultContainer.innerHTML = buttonDefinition.name;
    };
    buttonContainer.appendChild(button);
}
```

```html
<div id="buttonContainer"></div>
<div id="resultContainer"></div>
```

Comment: What is the purpose of using IIFE here?

Comment: You are totally right, it has no immediate use in this case. I removed it.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the element to the function and access the element data-attributes
In the below example I am passing data-name

```js
function f(element) {
  document.getElementById("dis").innerHTML = element.dataset["name"];
}
```

```html
<button data-name="JoeMae" onclick="f(this)">no.1</button>
<button data-name="TanakaMae" onclick="f(this)">no.2</button>
<button data-name="James" onclick="f(this)">no.3</button>
<button data-name="Deus" onclick="f(this)">no.4</button>
<p id="dis"></p>
```